# Multiple buttons clicking with disabled in the middle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a script for my enterprise that requires to click all of the buttons of the same kind in order to make a batch process.

The issue comes in the moment when you click a button, they all gets disabled for a while and enabled again, so I cannot batch-click these buttons basicly, resulting only on the first one clicked.

I already tried with a for loop for clicking them all, and putting

```
$("[disabled]").prop("disabled", false)
```

To prevent them from being disabled, but I only get the click on the first element of the series only.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.each` to loop over them

```
$("[disabled]").each(function(){

    $(this).prop("disabled", false)

});
```

```js
$("[disabled]").each(function(){
    $(this).prop("disabled", false)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" disabled/>
<input type="text" disabled/>
<input type="text" disabled/>
<input type="text" disabled/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm providing you 3 ways to do it :

```js
window.setInterval(function(){
  console.log('executed every second...');
    $("[disabled]").each(function(){ //1st way
        $(this).prop("disabled", false)
    });

    $("[disabled]").map(function(index, val) { //2nd way
        $(val).prop('disabled', false);
    });

    $('button[disabled]').each(function() { //3rd way
        $(this).prop('disabled', false);
    });
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" disabled>Button</button>
<button type="button" disabled>Button</button>
<button type="button" disabled>Button</button>
<button type="button" disabled>Button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks. Unfortunately none of these solutions work as it might need to do it in 'real-time' so it has to disable it in every moment.

Comment: Updated my answer! Check if it suits you @AndreRetroPie